# How do I calculate the price of 50g of a product, if the total grams of the product cost a certain amount

Tags: recreational-mathematics

I am looking for a formula that can calculate cost per 50g. e.g. How do I calculate the price of 50g of Pepper, if 300g costs 132? or How do I calculate the price of 50g of Salt, if 1000g costs 100?

What standard formula could I use?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to divide the monetary cost by the given grams, and multiply the result by $50~\text{g}$. Example:
$$
\text{Pepper}: \qquad \text{price per 50 g} =  \frac{132}{300~\text{g}} \cdot 50~\text{g} \approx 22 
$$
If you forget what should be multiplied by what, it's also rather easy to "test out" the numbers. Example: You know that 300 g costs 132. Therefore, one gram costs $132/300= 0.44$, right? Then two grams costs $2\times 0.44 = 0.88$, and 50 grams costs $50 \times 0.44 = 22$. Easy!

Comment: thanks a lot for this